# How can Node.js detect hung NFS filesystem

Tags: linux, node.js, nfs, readdir

I have mounted simple Node server that is trying to read data from a NFS drive, but my calls to `fs.readdir` never call the callback because the drive is hung or stuck. Is there anyway to detect that the NFS drive is stuck or maybe have a timeout for `fs.readdir`.

Comment: you can wrap the call in `setTimeout`, and then cancel the timeout if the `fs.readdir` callback happens. If the callback doesn't happen, before the timeout hits, assume the drive is stuck.

Comment: If the timeout callback returns first, is there anything I have to do to clean up the stuck call to `fs.readdir`? Will it leave dangling resources?